# How show editText character limit in buttom right corner of editText box?? Example below

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

[image]

The above image shows a editext, which has it's text limit displaying at the bottom right corner with 250 characters. As the user types characters in the editText the "250" decreases.

I have been trying to implement this into my edit text, but it's been a bit challenging. I have tried various stuff.
Just to let you know I am using a alertDialog, which has the editText inside it. The alertDialog then displays a xml, which has the editText attributes in it.

Thanks for the help!!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is very easy with android material. I hope its help:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textField"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:counterEnabled="true" --this makes counter enable
    app:counterMaxLength="20" -- this is the limittion 
    android:hint="@string/label">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]

or if you want just an EditeText you can use TextWatcher:

```
private TextView mTextView;
private EditText mEditText;
mTextView.setText("250");
private final TextWatcher mTextEditorWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
           //This sets a textview to the current length
           mTextView.setText(String.valueOf(250-s.length()));
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
}; 


mEditText.addTextChangedListener(mTextEditorWatcher);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. I have tried your solution, but it does not seem to work with just EditText. Is there a code that you have that works for my current XML code. I have updated the question with my current XML. I have tried using the material design editText, but I am getting result that i dont want. Thanks

Comment: @EdwardJames you can put your edit text in TextInputLayout. but  I updated my answer according to your need

Comment: NVM, your solution works much better, thanks for the help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
//xml 

     <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_comment"
                    style="@style/BusinessEditText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_160"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_border_comment"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:hint="Type here - Include your Order ID if it is connected to your order."
                    android:maxLength="500"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/text_gray"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_count"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="0/500"
                    android:layout_gravity="end" />



// inside java class            
        
        @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        
            }
        
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        
                if (count == 0) {
                    currentLine = currentLine - before;
                } else {
                    currentLine = currentLine + count;
                }
                Log.d("new line ", currentLine + "");
        
                dataBiding.tvCount.setText(currentLine+"/500");
        
        
            }
        
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        
            }
```